# How to get call string variable to Javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to define a variable "tag" in Javascript from '{{$a['tags']}}', but it is failed to do so.

I can call that in the HTML section but not in Javascript.

Can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
<article id="idea-info">

    <table class="table table-striped" id="productinfo_table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="productLabel">Title</td>
                <td class="productDesc">{{$a['title']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="productLabel">Tags</td>
                <td class="productDesc">{{$a['tags']}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</article>
```

```
    <script>

        var tags = {{$travelIdea['tags']}};
        var array = tags.split(',');

    </script>
```

Comment: If `$travelIdea['tags']` is a string, you can enclosed it with a `'` or `"` like:  `var tags = '{{$travelIdea['tags']}}';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
<script>

    var tags = "{{$travelIdea['tags']}}"; // add ""
    var array = tags.split(',');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{{$travelIdea['tags']}}` code is Blade syntax.

You can use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` to output in raw, which should work.

```
var tags = {!! $travelIdea['tags'] !!};
```

:)